# Install GarageBand on my son's iPad mini running iPadOS 15.x

Tags: applications, ipados, garageband

My son has expressed an interest in using GarageBand on his iPad mini. It is an older model, upgraded to the most recent version of iPadOS it can run, 15.7.8.

However, the current latest version of GarageBand requires iOS 16.x, and will not install from the App Store.

Is there any way to get the older version for this system?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to get the older version for this system?

Yes. You can install the last compatible version of GarageBand which supports running on iOS 15.7.

You'll need to logout from the App Store on the iPad mini and login using an Apple ID, using which you have bought/downloaded the older/compatible version of GarageBand for iOS/iPadOS.

Basically, if you have bought/downloaded an older version of the app from the App Store (the app in question is linked to your Apple ID as a purchase), you can download the last compatible version of the App is the current version of the app requires a newer version of iOS/iPadOS.

This does not work if the Apple ID currently logged into App Store does not have the app linked.

Once you have downloaded the last compatible version of the app, you can logout and re-login with the desired Apple ID in the App Store. The downloaded app will continue to work normally.